# Mixed Content Exception in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mixed-content, ninja-forms

I'm getting the following error when submitting a Ninja form that was integrated to the wordpress site.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my.domain/event/test-page/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://my.domain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

That is the only error that I'm getting. 
The site runs in HTTPS. 
A quick help is utmost appreciated.

Comment: You need to change all your url http to https.

Answer (score 3):

Install the plugin [Really Simple SSL](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/). Once installed and activated, click on "Go Ahead!" Blue button to activate it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you seeing the mixed content error in WordPress? Mixed content error in WordPress is caused by incorrect HTTPs/SSL settings. Often times it doesn’t affect your website’s functionality, but it can have adverse affects on your website’s SEO and user experience. In this article, we will show you how to fix the mixed content error in WordPress.

**For more details:**

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-fix-the-mixed-content-error-in-wordpress-step-by-step/

Answer (score 1):

You could try forcing all http requests to redirect to https. This is a blunt-force tool to solve issues like this, but not elegant.
Place this in your .htaccess file above the #BEGIN WordPress line

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Richard, Arta, and Gufran's answers are satisfactory. I simply offer an alternative. If you have a cpanel, go to domains and toggle the 'Force https Redirect' next to your domain