# Chrome blocks Wordpress login connection

Tags: php, wordpress, https

Apparently Chrome is blocking the connection of the Wordpress login page that I just installed.
The errors that come out are:

> wp-login.php:13 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.inf.utfsm.cl/~mvaras/wp-login.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.inf.utfsm.cl/~mvaras/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=5.2.3'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: It seems your site isn't properly configured to use SSL. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49485877/9131961).

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The error message pretty much tells you what's wrong: "the content must be served over https". You refer to a style sheet with plain http when the rest of the site is using https.

Comment: How did you get your SSL certificate? Are you running it behind Cloudflare or are you using Let's Encrypt?